# angular core no export members

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting error message that `angular/core` has no export members with any of the class below. In my package.config I am using 4.4.7. Any help would be great.

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, Inject, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Output, ElementRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy, NgZone, AfterViewChecked, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

Severity    Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"@angular/core"' has no exported member 'NgZone'.  C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Web\App\Components\Regimen\entry\editEntryDialogPanel.ts C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Web\tsconfig.json    3   Active
```

dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.7",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.4.7",
    "a": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-typedoc": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp4-run-sequence": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Comment: First question... Why are you using Angular 4? That's over 4 years old.

Comment: that is correct I am using Angular 4, I am in the process of upgrading .

Comment: Are dependencies installed? I'm assuming you're getting this error at compile time?

Comment: Yes dependencies are installed and its a  it looks like it compile error. The one `NgZone` that is having the problem.

Comment: I can't remember where NgZone is exported from that far back, but you might try following the major version steps from the update site: https://update.angular.io/